# Sencha touch 2.2 - Unnecessary action bar

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.2

While creating my native apk in `Sencha Touch 2.2 CMD version 3.1.2.342` after building the native app when i install the native apk on my android phone an **unnecessary action bar** is there.In other versions of sencha touch cmd it has not occurred.

Is there a way by which we can remove this action bar?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which action bar are you talking about? Could you please attach screenshot?

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia
The blue action bar at the top it gets generated by default in the new version of sencha touch cmd when buid native packaging of an app 
i have given you the screenshot link below
(http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9985/aoyf.jpg)

Comment: Anybody got any solutions for it ..???